# Hackerrank says my output is wrong even though the output matches perfectly

Tags: java, printing

I am doing an assignment on Hackerrank for Java where I had to perform some mathematical operations with scanner data. I ran the code with two samples and I got a 100% match with the expected output (see picture) but somehow Hackerrank still says there is no match. Is it possible that you print something and it looks the same but it is recognized as something different? I already tried to write the code in a different way so the result would be picked up correctly, by using  System.out.println but this was to no avail.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String []argh) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        String jj = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            String hh = "";

            for(int k=1;k<n+1;k++){
                long oo = a ;

                for (double o = 0; o < k; o++) {
                    oo = oo + b * (long) Math.pow(2, o);
                }
                hh = hh + " " + oo;
            }  

            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            System.out.print(hh);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

[image of Hackerrank result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uizhv.png)

Comment: see *what* picture?

Comment: Reformatted code to make it more readable

Comment: Can someone please reactivate this question? I added the picture and I would argue that it is relevant since Hackerrank is very popular and I have spoken to someone else on Hackerrank who encountered the same thing. Or at least explain what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no picture included to compare your code to output and/or expected output, I can only guess, but might be that **System.out.print("\n");** is not visible in html output, but is still picked up by the validation algorythm, and if lets say *5* is expected *\n5* would obviously be wrong, even if the *\n* whitespace part is invisible

Comment: Added the picture, unfortunately avoiding /n by using System.out.println yields the same result.